# CRON on CloudControl server

Tags: node.js, cron, cloudcontrol

I've setup a node.js server with cron jobs via [`node-cron`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), which is js-land cron implementation. I've noticed that sometimes the jobs are not launching, aparently without errors and following an unknown pattern.

Well, since this server is a free one, I was thinking that maybe it goes to sleep when there is no activity, so that the jobs are not launching. I've looked the docs and I haven't seen any clear indication on this.

I've already seen the Cron addon, but I'm not interested on it. I'll like to make it work within a js process.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, obviously I'm not discarding an error on my side, I just want to be sure about the "server goes to sleep" theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cloudControl uses Container idling (https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#deploying-new-versions) for free deployments.

If a free deployment (1 container with 128MB) does not get any requests within a timeframe of one hour the container is idled ("server goes to sleep").